# How to check if email exists with MYSQLi

Tags: mysqli

I'm 11 and I'm making a chat site for me and my friends. I'm using MYSQLi to handle the database things, and I'm kinda new to it. I always used normal mysql.

Oh! And if you can share a link to a mysqli tutorial, it would be great :)

Well here's my config file

```
   <?PHP                     


define("HOST", "localhost");  define("USER", "root");  define("PASSWORD", "****"); define("DATABASE", "secure_login");

$mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);

?>
```

The database is secure_login, then I have a table called members, and then a column named email in that table.

I included this to a file (register.php) where I have to check if the email exists or not. And if it exists, redirect to home.

If you guys can help me it would be cool!!! I hope to finish this soon :)

Comment: Don't use mysqli, use PDO instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd start with reading the `MySQLi` documentation at http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php, in specific the methods related to the class. If you are in need of a tutorial I would suggest to search on Google, there are loads of tutorials on the web.

As for your question, something like this should work:

```
$query = "SELECT email FROM members WHERE USER = ? AND PASS = ?";

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)){
        // Bind the parameters, these are the ?'s in the query.
        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $username, sha1($password));
        // Execute the statement
        if($stmt->execute()){
            // get the results from the executed query
            $stmt->store_result();

            $email_res= "";         
            // This stores the value of the emailaddres inside $email_res
            $stmt->bind_result($email_res);


            $stmt->fetch();

            // There is a result
            if ($stmt->num_rows == 1){

                             // Validate the emailadres here, check the PHP function filter_var() 

            }
            else {
                   // Not a valid email
            }
        }
        else {
            printf("Execute error: %s", $stmt->error);
        }

    }
    else {
        printf("Prepared Statement Error: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
    }
}
```

I hope this helps